# java.lang.InterruptedException causes web application not deploy

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, deployment, intellij-14

I use Intellij 14 + JDK 1.7 + Mac OS ,I tested this project in windows OS everything is fine and truly has been deploy but in mac OS have error ,I got this logs when i try deploy my web application in MAC OS, is there any way to find why i got this errors?

```
    2016-06-13 11:54:04,557] Artifact FIONUI:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
13-Jun-2016 11:54:14.162 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /Users/meysamfatheepanah/Documents/Projects/[3rdP]/apache-tomcat-8.0.9/webapps/manager
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (hsqldb.db.HSQLDB5548A5867F.ENGINE).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
13-Jun-2016 11:54:15.818 INFO [Thread-8] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
13-Jun-2016 11:54:15.872 INFO [Thread-8] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
13-Jun-2016 11:54:15.924 INFO [Thread-8] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
13-Jun-2016 11:54:15.924 SEVERE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of directories to complete
 java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:400)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:398)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1141)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1365)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1369)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

13-Jun-2016 11:54:19.383 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /Users/meysamfatheepanah/Documents/Projects/[3rdP]/apache-tomcat-8.0.9/webapps/manager has finished in 5,220 ms
13-Jun-2016 11:54:19.389 INFO [Thread-8] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
13-Jun-2016 11:54:19.461 INFO [Thread-8] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
13-Jun-2016 11:54:19.563 INFO [Thread-8] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
13-Jun-2016 11:54:19.565 INFO [Thread-8] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this problem .i change my tomcat version and i use JAVA 8 version.